# MVC Partial View Not Submitting Hidden Field Vale

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, hidden-field, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm developing an MVC 5 web application. One of the Views references a Partial View, like so

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel-body" id="TimeEntryPartial">
       @Html.Partial("_TimeEntryPartial", Model.TimeEntry)
    </div>
</div>
```

The Partial View then displays a form with several fields, one of which is a hidden field, like so

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddTimeEntry", "TimeEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frm", id = "frm" }))
{

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedUserID)

<div id="AddButtons">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="submit" id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" value="Add Entry">
    </div>
</div>

}
```

When the user submits the form, a HttpPost Action is called within a Controller, like so

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddTimeEntry(TimeEntryViewModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //code here
        int userID = model.SelectedUserID;
    }
}
```

All the values from the form are passed through in the ViewModel successfully, except for the SelectedUserID. This is always 0.

I thought it might be something to do with the field being hidden, therefore I changed it to a textbox and I could see the value inside it. However, again when the HttpPost Action was called, the value of property SelectedUserID was not contained within the ViewModel.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are getting a 0 it's because that's the value on the hidden, otherwise you should be receiving null if there is any problem with the identification of the field in the model binder.

Comment: @Bardo Sorry, but you're wrong. As stated in my question I also replaced the hidden field with a text box, and I could see the proper value held within it before the user submits the form. But still value is 0 when retrieved in the Http Post Action.

Comment: The code looks fine to me, I think we may need to see some additional scaffolding. What else exists in the main view? What does the browser see? Does the post to the server contain the correct details (check with Fiddler)?

Comment: Could you show please the model `TimeEntry` and the `TimeEntryViewModel`? And which Model your partialView is using?

Comment: Could whoever down voted this question please explain why? Seems ridiculous to down vote a question as well structured as this.

Answer (score 1):

Check your poco. If a field is not CORRECTLY set up as a property, the auto-wiring will ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have solved it by getting rid of partial view.

And everything works fine.